# Mac Pro 3,1 installation from USB freezes

Tags: boot, grub, macintosh

USB-stick made with Etcher but after boorin shows up only some cryptic text ...

Should DVD help or getting rid of Rock Ridge dual folders in iso ?

JK

Comment: Mac's usually require 'nomodeset' added to the boot parameters. However, 'some cryptic text' doesn't do anything to help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try rufus. See also:
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

When this also fails, please provide more info.